# The fastest way to get to Google paid ads

Tags: google-ads

Here's my question, it happened that we need to promote a website asap. it is a low competition local keyword. We want to be able to put it on paid ads (the coloured rectangle #1 in this image) http://www.aimadvantage.com/graphics/google-top-10.jpg

I know NOTHING about this kind of things. I just know that it can take several months before seeing results. I thought that paid advertising can make it quicker. Is it true?

I do not know whether it helps, but the exact keyword in keyword tool says nothing, but similar keyword says:

> global monthly search: 880
>    Local monthly search: 720
>    Competition:
>   high

Your advise is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing the point. Paid Ads provide potentially instant results depending on your budget (whether or not you can bid high enough per click to guarantee yourself a spot in spot #1).

[Google Adwords](http://google.co.uk/adwords) is Google's advertisers platform.

PPC (pay per click) advertising takes a lot of planning when done properly - you need to figure out what rate your visitors convert and how much their click is then worth to your site. That should then give you a basis as to what your PPC bid will be for visitors that arrive from various keywords.

**Organic** SEO would take months (most likely) to rank for the keywords you desire, but is technically free (unless you spend money on SEO...).